# In which year of education is the 々 symbol taught?

Tags: orthography, culture

A very similar question was asked here: [Does 々 have a kanji grade level?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/73307/does-%E3%80%85-have-a-kanji-grade-level)
but in the end the main question haven't really been answered, and the best answer was "you don't need to know".
Well, I do need to know - in which year of education is the 々 symbol taught to Japanese kids?

I can't accept "You don't need to know" as a valid answer, sorry.

Comment: I fear there may not be a definitive answer to this. I wonder if you can say what year you learnt the full stop (period). Here's someone else asking this on a different forum who didn't get a straight answer: https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1489506544

Comment: I would characterize the main answer of that question as "it's not officially defined" not "you don't need to know." The answerer said "don't worry about it" because it's not officially defined, not because they didn't want the person asking the question or something. So there likely is not one universal answer.

Comment: I said "don't worry" in the linked question because the asker was interested in 四字熟語, which was a clearly more advanced topic than the meaning of 々 itself. FWIW, I don't precisely remember when I learned 々, but I'm sure it was before I entered elementary school. I don't remember when 々 was "officially" taught to me (or whether my teacher taught it explicitly to me at all).

Comment: I wonder when you were explicitly taught about the reading of "Mr." (if you are educated in English)...

Answer (score 4):

I think this is really something that different kids will know at different times - because it's a symbol, not a kanji character, as the linked question answers.

I personally was taught this symbol and its origins by asking my teacher when I was in the middle grades of elementary school, but that's just me. I'm sure that there are others who knew about it earlier, and others who never learned about it from their teachers.

In fact, I remember that in my Japanese textbook, this symbol suddenly appeared in the text and there was no explanation of its meaning or origins.

However, when it appeared in the Japanese textbook, everyone probably already knew the meaning of the symbol somehow, and since the word itself is very common(like 時々, 人々, 堂々, etc...) , I guess no one asked about it.