# which kanji is this? i can't find it anywhere

Tags: meaning, symbols, writing-identification

I searched everywhere and I can't find it, maybe it is not kanji and i can't remember?[image]

Comment: Yes that isn't Kanji. Related: [Does 々 have a kanji grade level?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/73307/does-%E3%80%85-have-a-kanji-grade-level), [In which year of education is the 々 symbol taught?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/87499/in-which-year-of-education-is-the-%E3%80%85-symbol-taught)

Comment: Note that if you need to manually type it, you can *usually* enter くりかえし and it will be in the list of candidate words.

Answer (score 3):

That's not a kanji, which is why you're not finding it in kanji references.

That is called an "[iteration mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration_mark)", also known as an [[踊り字]{おどりじ}](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%B8%8A%E3%82%8A%E5%AD%97) in Japanese.  It basically means "repeat the previous character", like the "[ditto mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditto_mark)" or `〃` in English that means "repeat the previous word(s)".

There are multiple iteration marks used in Japanese writing, some of them more common historically and not used so much today.  The specific iteration mark in your screenshot is the most common one in modern usage.  This 々 is also called a *noma*, from the way that it looks a bit like a katakana ノ (*no*) combined with a katakana マ (*ma*).  If you enter a word like *iroiro* or *nadonado* using a Japanese input method editor (IME), you'll usually see this 々 as the second character in some of the options in the conversion candidate lists.